# Disable vertical spacing between UI elements in Eclipse Java IDE 2024-3

Tags: java, eclipse

Just tried the newest Eclipse Java IDE 2024-3, but there is now a ton of wasted vertical space between UI elements in multiple areas of the application such as project explorer and other views. As a result, only about a 1/3 of the information can be seen on screen versus the previous version.

Here is a screenshot of the prefpane exhibiting the issue.

Does anyone know of a way to disable this or is this a known bug?

[image]

Comment: I believe you are on MacOS. Here's how it [looks](https://imgur.com/a/wqMMgEY) on Windows 11.

Comment: There is a long discussion about this [here](https://github.com/eclipse-platform/eclipse.platform.ui/issues/1674)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: This is an open/ongoing issue. The Eclipse Developers are currently trying to find a solution and could use contributor help. Be kind and patient if you choose to participate: https://github.com/eclipse-platform/eclipse.platform.ui/issues/1674

## EDIT:

A fix has been merged, but the link above contains a hotfix that works as well.